# Android | Pre Populated datebase path

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am trying to include a pre populated database with my android app. When I declare the constant path eclipse errors and says "Do not hard code "/data/" use Context.getFilesDir().getPath() instead."

I thought I should declare the path like below
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.me.thisapp";

my sqlite db is located in my assets folder.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to include a pre populated database with my android app

I recommend that you [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for this.

> I thought I should declare the path like below private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.me.thisapp";

No. For example, that will be wrong for second and subsequent accounts on Android 4.2+ tablets.

Comment: I was following along with the tutorial here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-cIZoSa5bA

so I should not use an IngredientHelper?

Comment: @UPGRAYEDD: Oh, you will want an `IngredientHelper`. It would simply inherit from `SQLiteAssetHelper` and require very little code.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly, hard-coding paths is a bad idea.

I would recommend you to use this tiny library `SQLiteAssetHelper`(https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to manage pre populated databases and database upgrades in an easy way.

If you still want to do it by yourself, at least use the `ApplicationInfo.dataDir` property. Something like:

```
String databasePath = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/" + DB_NAME;
```